# "Undefined reference" when inlining method outside of the class definition

Tags: c++

I have this class (full code) in Screen.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Screen {
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
private:
    pos cursor = 0;
    pos height = 0, width = 0;
    std::string contents;
public:
    Screen() = default; // needed because Screen has another constructor

    Screen(pos ht, pos wd) : Screen(ht, wd, ' ') {}

    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, char c): height(ht), width(wd),
                                    contents(ht * wd, c) { }

    char get() const {
        return contents[cursor];
        }

    Screen& move(pos r, pos c);

    inline char get(pos ht, pos wd) const; // explicitly inline


    Screen& set(char);

    const Screen& display(std::ostream&) const;

    Screen& display(std::ostream&);

private:
        void doDisplay(std::ostream&) const;
};
```

and the implementation for it in Screen.cpp:

```
#include "Screen.h"
#include <iostream>

char Screen::get(pos r, pos c) const // declared as inline in the class
{
    pos row = r * width;      // compute row location
    return contents[row + c]; // return character at the given column
}

 inline Screen& Screen::move(pos r, pos c) {
    pos row = r * width;
    cursor = row + c;
    return *this;
}

Screen& Screen::set(char c) {
    contents[cursor] = c;
    return *this;
}

Screen& Screen::display(std::ostream& outputStream) {
    doDisplay(outputStream);
    return *this;
}

const Screen& Screen::display(std::ostream& outputStream) const {
    doDisplay(outputStream);
    return *this;
}

void Screen::doDisplay(std::ostream& outputStream) const {
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < height; ++h) {
            for (unsigned w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
                outputStream << contents[h*w];
            }
            outputStream << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My main file:

```
#include "Screen.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Screen myScreen(5, 5, 'X');
    myScreen.move(0,4).set('#').display(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int returnCode = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    return returnCode;
}
```

this produces the following linker error: undefined reference to `Screen::move(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)'

When I remove the "inline" from Screen::move, it works, but somehow the char at 0,4 doesn't get changed... I don't really know what's not working. I'm using Code::Blocks with the gcc compiler.

Edit: okay everything works fine when I remove the "inline" from the definition of the "move" method. But now my question is: why can't I specify "inline" in Screen.cpp?

Comment: My recollection (have not worked with C++ for many years) is that you must define a "home" for the method, since "inline" is only a suggestion/permission, not an order.

Comment: This basically is an exercise from the book "C++ Primer". The book tells me that it is valid to define inline outside of the class declaration. I don't know why it doesn't work for me. This is basically just a copy/paste from the book.

Comment: Also I read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/where-to-put-inline-keyword.html from this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3993003/1805439

Comment: I'll just double check: you are linking with Screen.cpp, right?

Comment: *"..but somehow the char at 0,4 doesn't get changed... "* : You mean on your *screen* ? Or within the `Screen` code object? Significantly different concepts, so you better elaborate.

Comment: Unrelated, but your display function is wrong: `outputStream << contents[h*w];`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're seeing, so I guess it must be something to do with your compiler / compile settings. Using inline like that should be fine, and tells the compiler to inline any calls within that compilation unit, but use the regular function outside the compilation unit.

Comment: That was a little white lie.  You promised you'll inline it but then you actually didn't.

Comment: oh no, wait, I can reproduce it. Now let's see if I can figure out why…

Comment: Hmm, seems I'm wrong in my views. Read point 2 here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3538.html

Comment: Look up `#pragma hashome`/`#pragma ishome`.

Answer (score 0):

You have inline in cpp file remove inline and it will be fine. I mean for the Screen::move function. Alternative move definition to header file.

Comment: Please read the question to the end: "When I remove the "inline" from Screen::move, it works, but somehow the char at 0,4 doesn't get changed"

Comment: Sorry I have never seen that kind of logical change due to inline vs non-inline. There is some other problem.

Comment: Inline normally needs to be placed in header file if to be effective in other translation units because otherwise the compiler cannot insert the whole body of the function.

Comment: When I think more. I can think of at least one case where you will have logical differences and that is if you use local static variables inside an inline function. Then you might end up with multiple copies of the static variable. That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into *.h or make it private and use it in *cpp, exclusively.